# WPF: How to extract Scrollbar From ScrollViewer programmatically?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

I'd like to access the Scrollbar from within my ScrollViewer.

I think it's hidden somewhere within the ScrollViewer's template, is there a way for me to access, and get a reference to it programmatically?

So if I have

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="myScrollViewer">
```

In the code behind I'd like to go:

```
ScrollBar scrollBar = myScrollViewer.GetScrollBar();
```

(obviously, I assume it'd be trickier than just that)

Comment: It should be that easy but for some unknown reason the developers decided to make it overcomplicated. If anyone here has any explanation as to why they have made it this was please let me know!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think I got it....

```
myScrollViewer.ApplyTemplate();

ScrollBar s = myScrollViewer.Template.FindName("PART_VerticalScrollBar", myScrollViewer) as ScrollBar;
```

Comment: The Template property is of type `ControlTemplate` it does not contain children that you can find.

Comment: `ApplyTemplate()` must be invoked on `ScrollViewer` in order to find scrollbars. If you invoke the code from this answer in `public override void OnApplyTemplate()` of a control that contains ScrollViewer, it will not yield any results without calling `myScrollViewer.ApplyTemplate()` first.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use the [`VisualTreeHelper.GetChild`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.getchild.aspx) method to walk the visual tree of the `ScrollViewer` to find the `ScrollBar`.

Since this method provides very low-level functionality and using it in high-level code will be painful, you will probably want to utilize a wrapper like [LINQ to visual tree](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/03/linq-to-visual-tree/).

Answer (score 1):

Get the `VisualTreeEnumerator` code from this blog [article](http://geekswithblogs.net/codingbloke/archive/2010/12/19/visual-tree-enumeration.aspx).

With this extension class in place:-

```
ScrollBar s = myScrollViewer.Decendents()
                 .OfType<ScrollBar>()
                 .FirstOrDefault(sb => sb.Name == "PART_VerticalScrollBar");
```

Comment: `ApplyTemplate()` must be invoked on `ScrollViewer` in order to find scrollbars. If you invoke the code from this answer in `public override void OnApplyTemplate()` of a control that contains ScrollViewer, it will not yield any results without calling `myScrollViewer.ApplyTemplate()` first.